# Why apps move from SD card to phone memory after upgrade and how to avoid it?

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, sd-card

After upgrade of any app - apps move back from SD Card to phone memory. 
After that, to save phone memory, I have to move upgraded app back to SD card.

Is any possibility to avoid this because it is very annoying?

I have Android 5.0.2 on Motorola E second gen phone.

Comment: Can you list the name of some apps which were moved back to phone memory after update?

Comment: [Apparently this happens on Lollipop](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/499205-apps-sd-card-moving-back-device-after-update-2.html#post4837851), and the only workaround for it is to set install location of the apps to SD card with [adb](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info). Run this command `adb shell pm set-install-location 2` and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: I'm seeing this on Android 7.0, Samsung Tab A. For example FeedMe, an RSS reader, with a cache of 1+ GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an existing behavior found in Lollipop. (May be an marketing strategy to make you buy expensive internal storage phones)

According to Lollipop the phone internal storage is referred as  SDCard  and removable SDCard as EXTERNALSD.

The apps is designed to be reside in SDCard (to support phone without external storage ) and hence the apps are installed back to internal storage.

This is fixed in Marshmallow were the EXTERNALSD can be configured to be an InternalStorage(SDCard).

So you can wait for an Marshmallow update for the device.

Comment: The question appears to be about upgrade, not the first time installation of an app. Can you prove that Android Lollipop is not smart enough to respect the current settings of user (that the app resides in external SD card) and decides to put the new APK (from update) into /data/?

Comment: @Firelord even in case of  updates  the apk will be downloaded again and installed. I dont have personal experience but I can quotes several examples from XDA as this is most asked question for device having external storage and running lollipop

Answer (score 1):

From [Anroid Central -Apps on SD card moving back to device after update](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/499205-apps-sd-card-moving-back-device-after-update.html#post4601011)

> Actually, it did not happen in KitKat. It is a new (and very
>   irritating) phenomenon with Lollipop. Basically Google just keep
>   forgetting about SD cards (probably wish they didn't exist); which is
>   kindof annoying given that their subsidiary, Motorola, is still
>   selling phones that have too little main memory (8Gb) to run
>   effectively without having most of your apps on the SD card.

so, the only (not recommended) solution is downgrade the device from Android 5.0 to Android 4.4..

Comment: The quote reads like an opinion written as a technical fact. Can you support it with personal experience with both Lollipop and KitKat (explain the process you followed) or with credible and technical sources that we can use to verify your claim.

Comment: [rfoster12 on androidcentral claims that it didn't happen with Galaxy S2, S3, S4 (and also S5 with KitKat) but happens only on S5 with Lollipop](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5/499205-apps-sd-card-moving-back-device-after-update.html#post4611585)