# ZTE Obsidian running Android 5.1 doesn't save files to SD card.

Tags: sd-card, storage, ram

When I try to update apps through Google Play I can't save the app to the SD card. In settings I chose SD card as the default drive but it still doesn't work. Is there anyway to make the system recognise the SD card? I constantly get insufficient storage space messages.

Comment: You're most likely dealing with the issue noted here: [Why apps move from SD card to phone memory after upgrade and how to avoid it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/135321)

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Android do not allow for install to SD card. The cache can be saved here (which you've already enabled the option for) but installing the application directly to the SD card is no longer supported.

Comment: I thought that was only in 6.0?

Comment: Nope, I've used Android 5.0, 5.1, and 5.1.1 with no luck. Though it looks like this could just be an issue with the app developer not updating their code to work with the new SD card access model: http://www.androidcentral.com/lollipop-brings-changes-way-your-sd-card-works-kind-youll